# Clicking on just the text of block elements

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

I have a fixed-size `div` in which I am positioning several inline `a`'s using the `flexbox` layout. My problem is that I also need to respond to clicks on the `div`, outside the text of the anchors, but `flexbox` is forcing their display to `block` so they take up all the available space, leaving no room for the user to click on the background `div`.

HTML:

```
<div class="poem">
    <a class="title">Title</a>
    <a>1919</a>
    <a>Lead</a>
    <a>Bachus</a>
</div>
```

Compiled CSS (I'm using SASS):

```
.title { 
    font-size: 1.85em; 
}

.poem {
    width: 12.5em;
    height: 12.5em;
    padding: .0625;
    background-color: rgba(gray, 0.5);
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.poem > a {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.poem > a:first-child {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}           

.poem > a:first-child:hover {
    background-color: rgba(255, 165, 0, 0.5);
}
```

[This pen](http://codepen.io/recat/pen/raIGx) shows how I want to lay out the elements, and [here](http://codepen.io/recat/pen/BvIwE) is how they should actually work when hovered/clicked.

My question is whether there is any way to stop `flexbox` from forcing the elements' display to `block` and keep them `inline` or, alternatively, to detect whether a click was made specifically on an element's text.

I realize I could probably wrap each `a` in a `div`, but that would be non-semantic, so I'd rather leave it as a last resort.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.poem {
    align-items: flex-start;
}

.poem > a:first-child {
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yGArn